# VisualStudio 2015 is locking sln files on TFS after opening solution, however no changes to sln file

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

Currently we use VS2015 and TFS 2015.

Before using Visual Studio 2015 as a team, there were no problems.

After starting to use VS2015, once you open a solution from source control explorer, visual studio is locking the solution file. 
But it is not changing the file.

This is so disturbing, because multiple warning messages shown right after opening a locked solution file.

How can we solve this weird behaviour of VS2015?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the [tf lock /lock:none](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47b0c7w9(v=vs.100).aspx) command to remove lock if you don't want to set locks on these version controlled items.

Additionally, please have a check on Daniel Mann's reply for further ideas on  working with TFS lock [TFS checkout lock best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949981/tfs-checkout-lock-best-practices)

Comment: well, tf lock /lock:none unfortunately does not unlock files locked by someone else. and my team does not let multiple checkout because of their reasons that i disagree with them.

Comment: You can unlock other's changes with the tf undo command if you're the project administrator (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfssetup/archive/2012/03/21/unlock-the-files-checked-out-by-other-users.aspx , this blog applies to TFS2015 as well). However, if as it is your team's rule to disable multi check out, undo pending changes every time is not efficient. And, back to your issue, when you open the solution in VS2015, is the opened solution checked out? As far as I know that, a older version of VS will check out opened file automatically; however, a higher version VS does not.

Comment: Yes you are right, this is about visual studio 2015, vs2013 did not have this problem, however some older versions have. Now it appeared on vs2015 again. So I hope someone has a solution for vs2015.

Comment: @mecek, the issue is not reproduced in my VS2015 Enterprise. So which edition of VS2015 you're working with? As your VS2015 acts unexpectedly, try the following command: 1). devenv /resetsettings 2). devenv /SafeMode 3). Devenv /ResetSkipPkgs

Comment: @"Vicky - MSFT" Firstly thanks for dealing with the issue. To reproduce the issue: TFS 2015 with multicheckout disabled and VS2015 Enterprise or Community editions both have the issue